# Error message when I open the product page in admin backend

Tags: magento2, database, no-such-entity-exception

I transferred my database to a new site and now get an error message when I open product page in admin dashboard "Invalid entity_type specified:"
and other products have this error "No such entity with id=9". I'm using Magento CE 2.1.9

How do I fix that? Can anyone help me?

```
[2018-01-30 12:51:56] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid entity_type specified:  in /home/storesah/public_html/m4/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php:350

[2018-02-06 07:33:04] main.WARNING: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/storesah/public_html/m4/pub/media/catalog/product/r/y/ryobi_chain_saw_cs-2240.jpg in /home/storesah/public_html/m4/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71
```

Answer (score 0):

> [2018-02-06 07:33:04] main.WARNING: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/storesah/public_html/m4/pub/media/catalog/product/r/y/ryobi_chain_saw_cs-2240.jpg in /home/storesah/public_html/m4/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71

Typically this error means that image has been deleted from the `media` directory, but the link to it still exists in the database. I'll recommend you to upload image anew.

> [2018-01-30 12:51:56] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid entity_type specified:  in /home/storesah/public_html/m4/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php:350

This error means that you trying to work with the unexistent entity (like a `customer` or `product` in the base Magento, but added by third-party module). This entity used in the edit product page, but does not exist in the database. You can debug it in the corresponding class:

1. Open product edit page.
2. Open `magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php` on your server and change this code:

   ```
   if (!$entityType->getId()) {
       throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid entity_type specified: %1', $code));
   }
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   if (!$entityType->getId()) {
       $e = new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid entity_type specified: %1', $code));
       var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
       die();
   }
   ```

or if you have xDebug on your server use it, it's preferred way.

Reload the recently opened product edit page in your browser and check exception trace. From it you can find a module which trying to load empty \ nonexistent entity (or update your question - add trace and I'll try to help you).

**PS: after debugging do not forget to remove debug code which you added!**